# Bing Maps v7 Module not loading

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bing-maps

I'm trying to use the [Well Known Text Reader/Writer](http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Well%20Known%20Text%20Reader%2fWriter) but I'm having issues loading the module. I load the module here:

```
Microsoft.Maps.registerModule("WKTModule", "../../JS/WKTModule.js");
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("WKTModule");
```

I then define a layer to add shapes to:

```
var countyLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
```

But when I try to use the model in this next block, I get the error "WKTModule is not defined"

```
jQuery.each(config.CountyData, function (k, v) {
    var polygon = WKTModule.Read(v.Value, { polygonOptions: { fillColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(50, 255, 0, 0), strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(255, 0, 0, 0), strokeThickness: parseInt(1)} });
    countyLayer.push(polygon);
});
```

**EDIT: Found Fix**

What I'm guessing it happening is that the Module isn't loaded in time when I try to use it for that read. So, instead of just calling the method after the load, I added the function to a setting on the load so it will call the function once loaded. Here's the new code:

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("WKTModule", { callback: addCounties });

var addCounties = function() {    
    jQuery.each(config.CountyData, function (k, v) {
        var polygon = WKTModule.Read(v.Value, { polygonOptions: { fillColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(50, 255, 0, 0), strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(255, 0, 0, 0), strokeThickness: parseInt(1)} });
        countyLayer.push(polygon);
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you sure `../../JS/WKTModule.js` is the right path?

Comment: @Rocket : I've tried using that path, the absolute path, and the path to an external site where that file is. None of them have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are trying to use the module before it is loaded. Don't forget that it is an external file and should be loaded.

You can use the `callback` option to call a function when the module is loaded.

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("WKTModule" {callback: function() {

    console.log('the module is ready now');
}});
```